# PYTHONPATH is overwritten by something else

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04

I have a problem importing `xlrd` python module which is located both in `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7` and in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. I'd like to import one from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, but no matter what I do `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7` stays on top of my sys.path!

I did modify my PYTHOPATH without success. The last line of my .basrc is

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

so I'd think dist-packages must be on top of sys.path!?

Could someone help me?
This is **ubunutu 12.04lts**, **python2.7**, **iPython 0.12.1**
Of course if I edit sys.path manually - everything works fine - I get xlrd of the right version, but that's ugly right? I want to know what's putting `/usr/lib/pymodules...` on top of the list!?

Here is my sys.path:

```
['',  '/usr/bin',  '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',  '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.7.3-py2.7.egg',  '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-5.4.2-py2.7.egg',  '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',  '/home/venevs/Dropbox/usr/local/lib/my_packages',  '/usr/lib/python2.7',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

Comment: Perhaps check the contents of `os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]`

Comment: Consider using virtualenvs which will give you your own python environment. http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: os.environ["PYTHONPATH"] output is, as expected:   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/venevs/Dropbox/usr/local/lib/my_packages'.

Comment: still have no idea  where this `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7` is coming from, and why cannot I overwrite it by `PYTHONPATH`?! I've heard of `virtualenv`, but this time I have full(sudo) access to the machine and I just want to be able to fix such simple, at a first glance, things